# Will this OP AMP work for this application?

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, circuit-protection, batteries, low-battery

I designed the following circuit in CircuitLab. My question isn't about the whole thing, but rather about the TL081 Operation Amplifiers that circuitlab uses as a default(data sheet found [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl081.pdf)).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGFGI3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This design is meant to be a low-voltage cutoff circuit for an electric bicycle where there are 3 batteries - each with 4 cells. The first thing I do is use comparators to find the voltage across each cell. At that point, my goal is to use another op amp to determine if the voltage of the cell is below a 3.3V  threshold and then pass either 5V(if the cell voltage is above the threshold) or 0V(if the cell voltage is below threshold) through some digital logic.

I know Circuit Lab isn't the best when it comes to analysis, but I am wondering if the TL081 will work as it does here in Circuit Lab. Im very new to operational amplifiers and the datasheet didn't seem to have any clear answers for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The TL081 is  rather dated op-amp that is used mostly as a reference model and to repair old designs, it was pretty smart in its day.  Better lower current, voltage and improved spec op amps are to be found from multiple vendors. You might consider using an A/D converter with an input MUX to measure the junction voltage between each cell and then do the rest in software.  You may also find that a decent charge controller circuit will maintain the cells at reasonably balanced and you need only monitor the total battery voltage.  Also worth checking what others have done to save a lot of time.

Comment: Your circuit is unreadable and I couldn't make out any of the power supply conenctions to the op-amps or comparators. Telepathy might help but I suspect your design will be wrong in several areas. Minimum supply voltage for TL081 is 10V or +/-5V.

Comment: You have three 7805 regulators that are labeled as providing -5V, 3V3, and 5V. How is that supposed to work? And you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how op-amps work.

Comment: @uint128_t You're not wrong! I have no experience with OP AMPS whatsoever so I appreciate your taking that into consideration.

Comment: Those 12 cells in series are going to give over 50v. Even if your set of 7805s magically became something more appropriate, no opamp that I'm aware of is going to tolerate having its inputs so much higher than its supply.

Comment: @Andyaka - The circuit is readable if you edit the post, then edit the schematic and zoom in. Then back out and quit the editor. Doesn't make the circuit work, of course, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been indicated, this is not a good circuit, but I'll try until I get tired.

Let's start with function. Apparently you want to do the following:

1) Run each battery through a difference amplifier to produce a (more or less) 3.7 volt level.

2) compare each level to 3.3 volts with a comparator

3) if any cell in a 4-call pack is low, turn on an LED

4) if all 3 packs are good, do (something incomprehensible) involving a 1k/100 uF capacitor time constant, and

5) if all the cells are good, and your (something) is OK, turn on the MOSFET and apply voltage to your load.

So.

To start, as brhans pointed out, a 7805 will not produce -5 volts from 12 volts, so you'll need an entirely different approach to providing op amp power. And, of course, a 7805 won't produce 3.3, either.

1) Except for a few odd exceptions, the input to an op amp must be within the op amp power supply voltages. In this case, that means +/- 5 volts. Since the peak voltage, at the top of the battery string, is about 48 volts, this circuit would fry virtually your entire array of chips. There are ways around this, but only one will work for "regular" op amps, and that not well. You can divide the battery voltages down to something the opamps can handle, like so

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3GDBP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each battery is monitored by a difference amplifier with at gain of 1/4, and because of the resistor ratios, 48 volts at the top of a 12-cell stack will produce a maximum voltage of 10 volts at the op amps. If the TL081s (well, you'd want to use TL084s for this sort of assembly) are powered by +15/-5, they will work well. Because the gain is 1/4, the output of each difference amplifier for 3.3 volts is 0.825.

Each difference amplifier is followed by a gain of 5 amplifier, which boosts 0.825 to 4.125.

The output of the gain amplifiers is fed to a comparator which should not be a TL081, but something like an LM339, which is also powered by +15. A more modern comparator with a better input range, can be powered by +5.

Each comparator has 10 mV of hysteresis. That is, if it triggers at 4.125 for a drop in voltage, the voltage will have to rise to 4.135 volts to change the output to a high. This is necessary because, once you switch off the motor, the unloaded batteries will increase their voltage. If you don't have any hysteresis the system will oscillate on and off, and you won't like that. If the hysteresis in inadequate, and you do still get oscillation, increase the value of the resistor from the output of the gain amplifier.

While not shown, you must provide a decoupling capacitor to each power supply of each package. A 0.1 uF ceramic cap connected to ground is a good default. A pcb with a ground plane is an excellent idea for this large a project.

EDIT - There is a big problem with this circuit. As long as it is connected, the difference amplifiers will draw current, discharging the battery. And you cannot disconnect this with a simple OFF switch. For a 12-cell battery stack you'll need to disconnect all 12 measurement points. While you should have no difficulty finding a 13-pin connector which you can physically unplug, this will be nothing like convenient.

Comment: Hey thanks for this amazing response. This was the first circuit I have ever designed and I see now how many gaping holes there were in it. Although extremely embarrassing, this was a tremendous learning experience which I value greatly. You have some great ideas but I think I will start from scratch and end up using something like [this](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6802-1). Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

That circuit will not work,  everything is wrong with it.
especially the first column.

in the first column comparators don't work like that, they they output high or low depending on only which of the two inputs has the higher voltage, they do not convert the difference to a voltage.

Comment: and a 7805 isn't going to give you a -5v supply, and what are those round summing symbols supposed to represent in real life?

Comment: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html

Will this work?

Comment: @brhans This is old. I only used those because circuitlab had them and it was nice and easy. This is the plan here http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/electronics-components-how-to-add-voltage-to-an-op.html

Comment: @Daniel Notice those resistors in the schematics you linked? Those resistors are important. But even with changes, you're going to need a wide supply voltage to measure each battery with a diff-amp.

Comment: @uint128_t Can you explain what you mean about needing the wide supply voltage to measure each battery?

Also- I'm going to remake this with all the resistors in place for both the differential op amp and the additive op amp configurations. I'll make a new post when I do

Comment: that difference amplifier will work, but care must be taken to keep the op-amp inputs in range. LM324 might be a better suited op-amp here

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some dedicated Battery monitoring parts. For example, Linear Tech has these.

http://www.linear.com/parametric/Multicell_Battery_Stack_Monitor for example?